# Proper handling of resources in asp.net core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, dependency-injection, clr

I am trying to properly manage resources in asp.net core. Is it necessary to register every object I create inside the dependency injection container? If I register an object inside the dependency injection container what happens to objects I create inside that object? For example:

```
services.AddScoped<ISimpleObject1, SimpleObject1>();

public class SimpleObject1 : ISimpleObject1 {
        public const string Message = "Hello";
        public SimpleObject2 simpleObject2 = new SimpleObject2() { 
            Message2 = "Hello again"; 
        };
}
```

I'm fairly new to asp.net core and the CLR runtime. My thinking is that I only need to register classes that are IO intensive or Network resource heavy. I would like to write applications in the most performant manner possible so any advice or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general Dependency Injection is not related to solving performance or resource issues. It is a design pattern for making your classes loosely coupled and separating concerns using the IoC principle.

You do not *have* to register all dependencies as services. It depends on your application architecture. As a rule of thumb, I create and register services when there is a clear boundary between the responsibility of the classes.

The object (SimpleObject2) you instantiate in the service you have registered will have the same life-time as your service (ISimpleObject1).

See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/extensions/dependency-injection#service-lifetimes for more info on service life-time.

Answer (score 0):

I order to register an object with the dependency service, you need to specify the type that it implements/represents in the dependency service.

Your code probably doesn't work as it is because the class `SimpleObject1` isn't inheriting/implementing `ISimpleObject1`.

That being said, you're passing two types here. The type it represents, (`ISimpleObject1`), and the implementation type (`SimpleObject1`). The dependency service won't look through objects to register them because it doesn't know what type they represent. This might also be a performance thing. Reflection is very expansive.

My suggestion would be to register every service you need with `services.Add*()` methods.